# How to implement Update subquery in sql server 2017 I want to update one column using multiple select but its showing subquery error

Tags: sql-server, subquery

```
UPDATE temp_hourly_stats SET peak_location_percentage =( 
(SELECT TOP(1) peak_location_count as peak_location_count FROM temp_hourly_stats where time_range = (select concat( DATEPART(hh, DATEADD(hh,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) ,'-', DATEPART(hh, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))as time_range) order by id desc)UNION
(SELECT TOP(1) total_count as total_count FROM temp_hourly_stats where time_range = (select concat( DATEPART(hh, DATEADD(hh,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) ,'-', DATEPART(hh, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))as time_range) order by id desc)Union
(select (peak_location_count*100)/total_count as peak_loc_percentage))
```

The error I am getting is this:-
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subquery has 2 UNION's, so your it returns 3 records. So thats the reason you are getting the error. There are a couple of ways to handle your request. 
Try something like this:

```
  UPDATE temp_hourly_stats
SET         temp_hourly_stats.peak_location_percentage = ( CA1.peak_location_count * 100 ) / CA2.total_count
FROM        temp_hourly_stats
CROSS APPLY 
            (
                     SELECT TOP(1)
                              peak_location_count AS peak_location_count
                     FROM     temp_hourly_stats
                     WHERE    time_range =
                              (
                                     SELECT concat( Datepart(hh, Dateadd(hh,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) ,'-', Datepart(hh, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))AS time_range)
                     ORDER BY id DESC ) AS CA1
CROSS APPLY
            (
                     SELECT TOP(1)
                              total_count AS total_count
                     FROM     temp_hourly_stats
                     WHERE    time_range =
                              (
                                     SELECT concat( Datepart(hh, Dateadd(hh,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) ,'-', Datepart(hh, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))AS time_range)
                     ORDER BY id DESC ) AS CA2
```

Comment: Sir I did the same way you told but its showing Error near CA2

Comment: I edited your answer so that it may be clear to you

Comment: Hi Utkarsh, I had one opening parenthesis too many. Please try again

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use IN operator instead of "=" operator in update query.

Like this

UPDATE temp_hourly_stats SET peak_location_percentage IN( 
(SELECT TOP(1) peak_location_count as peak_location_count FROM temp_hourly_stats where time_range = (select concat( DATEPART(hh, DATEADD(hh,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) ,'-', DATEPART(hh, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))as time_range) order by id desc)UNION
(SELECT TOP(1) total_count as total_count FROM temp_hourly_stats where time_range = (select concat( DATEPART(hh, DATEADD(hh,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) ,'-', DATEPART(hh, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))as time_range) order by id desc)Union
(select (peak_location_count*100)/total_count as peak_loc_percentage))

Comment: Sorry, some where your inner query return more than one result, please check your query

Comment: check this query "select (peak_location_count*100)/total_count as peak_loc_percentage" and this query "select concat( DATEPART(hh, DATEADD(hh,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) ,'-', DATEPART(hh, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))as time_range) order by id desc"

Comment: Sir if I use this query than my logic will change and my target is to first take out the peak_location_count than take out total_count and than take out the percentage of these data and put it in a single column which is peak_location_percentage

Comment: May be adding union to my query is not a right way?!!

Comment: No need to use union query, just add IN operator wherever you use "=" operator